# Why intel 6th generation show in IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers driver instead 7th gen(my proccessor)?

Tags: windows-10, device-manager, intel-core-i5

my laptop have intel i5 7200u which is 7th generation. why in device manager at IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers, it is written 6th gen? am I install incorrect driver?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you running this on a 100-series motherboard (e.g. Z170)? The SATA controller is part of the PCH which is part of the motherboard, not the CPU.

Comment: “am I install incorrect driver?” If you had the incorrect driver installed your system wouldn’t even boot into Windows.  I highly encourage you to leave it alone.  How did you, exactly, determine you have a i5 7200U exactly?

Comment: @Bob hmm.. no, it is a laptop

Comment: @Ramhound i check it in properties of This PC, CPU-Z, dxdiag

Comment: @Aorstab ...laptops still have a motherboard and still use a PCH, and you can identify the chipset family under the `System devices` section.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing a real problem. The Processor and the IDE/ATA ATAPI controllers are two separate pieces of hardware. As a rule the IDE/ATA ATAPI controller represents the chipset so you are running a Series 6 chipset with a 7th gen processor. They have been doing that with servers for a long time.

Go back to the manufacturer and see what chipser they are using and how they refer to it....